# Sharing an ArcGIS Experience Builder Webapp

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-experience-builder

I have built a geospatial webapp on Experience Builder from my AGOL account, on advice from a supervisor who told me to use AGOL and not Enterprise because Experience Builder on AGOL had several features that were not yet available for Enterprise (such as Bookmarks).

However, now that it's ready I cannot share it with my clients because they have no AGOL account and I have no permission to set the sharing setting to "Everyone" due to my company's internal organization, plus the information on the webapp is confidential. I need a workaround.

Could I share the webapp on sharepoint?
MI have no idea how to do it though.

Answer (score 2):

Sharing the application to your SharePoint site will probably not solve anything unless SharePoint is somehow managing access on your behalf. Meaning, the App, Map and Data are still "private" (not shared), but SharePoint can authenticate as a trusted user to AGOL and allow anyone with the SharePoint access the ability to see what has been shared to SharePoint. If that worked, I'd actually question if that falls within the AGOL ToS as it would probably be using a single account, effectively "sharing" it with multiple people (those who have sharepoint access).

I can't think of any solution that allows an unauthenticated person (your intended clients) access to the information you want to keep internal and private. The two concepts are exclusive to each other.

Could you provide them logins to your org and using roles and groups, limit what they can see to just the project you're working on?

Or could your client setup their own AGOL Org with their own logins? You could setup collaboration between your Org and theirs, sharing just the information they're supposed to see. On their side, that information is protected by their own accounts and permissions.

Comment: The clients are part of my organization, but they do not have an AGOL account. Portal allows people in my organization to view Portal content without an account, and I've had no trouble sharing mine in the past, but apparently AGOL doesn't - even if I set the sharing to 'organization', people still need to log in with their AGOL account first.

Comment: There's a lot fundamentally different between Portal and AGOL in terms of accounts. Your on-premise deployment might make use of Active Directory and SSO. In theory, all 174238 (made up number) people in your company could have a Viewer account without each member having to do anything besides simply clicking a link. The only way for someone _without_ an account to view something in AGOL is to make it __public__

Comment: Further to my explanation of accounts and sharing, I think the _right_ solution here is to make use of ArcGIS Experience Builder __Developer__ (which has the same features as AGOL Experience Builder), and deploy the app within your network. So your clients in your org (all behind the same firewall) will see and use it just like any other Portal content.

Comment: I understand, thank you. Now I have actually made a new app on Portal and set the sharing options to "Organization" - this should make it viewable to everyone in the organization, right? I know Portal generates an account automatically at first login, or so I got told.

Comment: Shared to "organization" still requires an account. But as you said, it sounds like you have automatic account creation. In that scenario, as long as the created account has viewer permissions, then yes, sharing to the organization is basically the same as sharing "public"